# On lower zoom polygons don't show

Tags: leaflet, node-js

I'm working with Leaflet and nodejs and when a polygon layer is loaded when the map view is at world map, the polygon don't shows, I have to zoom in at approximately zoom 10 or 13 to show polygons.

I was trying to use this plug-in but realy don't know how to use it. The lib https://github.com/oliverroick/Leaflet.Deflate

---

To represent the map I use this

```
    var layers = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: features,
      properties: {}
    };

    showLayers = L.geoJson(layers);

    leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {

      showLayers.addTo(map);
    });
```

And I try to use it but don't know where?

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour of Leaflet.Deflate plugin: when a polygon width or height is smaller than the map `minSize` option (default: 10px) at the current map zoom, it is replaced by a marker.

Make sure you have the marker images so that you can see them as well.

When you zoom in, you increase the polygon size, until it is eventually bigger than the minSize, and the marker is replaced by the polygon itself.

Comment: Thanks @ghybs for the replay, but how do I use it? in the github page it says that I have to use var map = L.map.deflate('map', {minSize: 20})
but where I put that code? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `L.map('map')`… but if you have been able to test Leaflet.Deflate already, you should have already used that line of code?

Comment: I've edited my question with the code I use to represent the layers.

Comment: Can you kindly detail what `leafletData.getMap()` does / how it is specified? I am not sure this is standard Leaflet API.

Comment: Yes sory for that, I'm using angular leaflet directive from tombatossals, in this link is an example of usign leafletData.getMap, http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/controls/draw-example

Comment: I am not sure angular-leaflet-directive is compatible with Leaflet.Deflate plugin unfortunately. Maybe you can modify the behaviour of the directive by changing [that line](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/src/directives/leaflet.js#L95)?